# CSS: Overflow not working

Tags: html, css

In this example, which I'm trying to understand, definitely overflow happens, but it doesn't work. why?

```
body, html, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html{

  background-color: #666;
}
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 780px;
  background-color: #99ccff;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div{
  background-color: #b57c12;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 820px;
}
p{
  background-color: #f7f0b7;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
```

**HTML: Inside Body Tag**

**Emmet:** `div>p>lorem10`

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, it doesn't overflow because you have `overflow: hidden;` for your `body`.

Comment: @Lal It overflows, but it doesn't get **hidden**

Comment: Your code seems to be working perfectly..see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zan7pwqe/)...may be due to caching..check again after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: fix  the `height` and  `overflow:auto`

Comment: @Lal It still overflows. Can you show your result with an image? Nothing is hidden. div extends beyond body tag, it's container.

Comment: Are you able to see the scrollbars in the fiddle? @Meysam

Comment: @Lal no. not in firefox and chrome.

Comment: then how do you say that `overflow:hidden` is not working..it is working fine..otherwise you will be seeing scrollbars in your browser.

Comment: @lal this is my result=> [link](https://snag.gy/fcRuiB.jpg). if I say hidden, whatever which passes the boundaries or body, should be clipped off

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zan7pwqe/2/) @Meysam

Comment: @Meysam check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Body should always cover 100% of the width. I would suggest you set a inner wrapper instead that you use overflow hidden on.

https://jsfiddle.net/jjxurtpk/

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
  test
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
  width:400px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#eee;
  padding:20px;
}
.wrapper div{
  width:500px;
  background:#ddd;
  padding:10px;
}
```

update: https://jsfiddle.net/jjxurtpk/1/

I believe the overflow hidden does not fully apply unless the background (html) does not have overflow hidden. I'm not sure why. It could just be thats how browsers simply render the body tag.

Comment: My problem is not with changing the code, coming up with new ideas, instead I want to know why, when there is an overflow, in body, it doesn't make it hidden!

Comment: Hahaha...looks very similar to my answer (I mean your fiddle)... ;)

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm moving this discussion too far, but no one explained why there should be overflow in html? I'm not looking for hacks or tricks to solve things.

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zan7pwqe/4/)

You will have to add `overflow:hidden` to `html` too ..

See the below CSS

```
body,
html,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: #666;
  overflow:hidden; /* <---------------add this----------*/
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 780px;
  background-color: #99ccff;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  background-color: #b57c12;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 820px;
}

p {
  background-color: #f7f0b7;
  border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a height on the body, and apply overflow: hidden to the html.

See demo [here](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/oYMrgp)

```
html{
  overflow: hidden;
}
body{
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why is that? definitely, overflow is happening inside body, and what's the reason behind height?